# Error retrieving value from form field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm a dabbler when it comes to coding so I have a basic to intermediate understanding of various languages.  I have a HTML form with a number of fields, one of which I'm trying to grab when a button is pressed but I'm getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null**

Here's my code in total:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testForm.css">
    <title>Create Incident Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Whittle ERP Ecosystem</header>
    <p style="font-family:GE Inspira Sans;font-size:18px">This form is for 
raising Incidents against the pillar applications in the Whittle ERP 
Ecosystem</p>
    <p style="font-family:GE Inspira Sans;font-size:18px;color:red;font-
weight:bold">ALL FIELDS ARE MANDATORY</p>
    <form id="frm1" action="" method="post" name="incForm">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>User Detail</legend>
        <label for="user-SSO">*SSO</label>
        <input type="text" name="usrSSO" id="usrSSO" value="108013590" required>
        <input type="Button" onclick="validateSSO()" value="Post"> 
        <label for="user-tel">&nbsp*Contact Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user-tel" id="user-tel" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>System</legend>
        <label for="*Choose System">Choose System:</label>
        <select name="system" id="system" required>
            <option value="R12">R12</option>
            <option value="Proficy">Proficy</option>
            <option value="TipQA">TipQA</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>*Brief Description</legend>
        <textarea rows="1" cols="60" name="bDesc" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>*Detailed Description</legend>
        <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="dDesc" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Action</legend>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>



<script>

    function validateSSO(){

       document.write("Starting function.....!<br />")
       var fname = document.getElementById("usrSSO");
       document.write(fname.value)
       var strOutput
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
           strOutput = xmlhttp.responseText
           document.write("Function value: " + strOutput + "<br />")
       }
   };
           xmlhttp.open("GET", "url", true)
           xmlhttp.send();

       if (strOutput == "A" ) {
           window.alert("Condition met - SSO is valid")
      }else{
           document.write("Nope - invalid");
     }

   }



   </script>
```

I've seen a few articles dealing with this but none seem to help me!  I'm just trying to grab the contents of the usrSSO text field to use in a validation function.  What have I missed/screwed up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I've seen a few articles dealing with this but none seem to help me!"_ - well then explain _how not_, please. You should have been able to find enough explanations of what causes the error, and how to debug it. So, tell us what that lead you to so far.

Comment: For start, you should have some error handling like `if (fname) { document.write(fname.value); }`, other then that I can't replicate your error it works fine for me.

Comment: CBroe - indeed I have and apologies for not including it originally.  Most info points to the fact that either there is no element with that id, or that the value is not populated when the function runs.  I've made sure the <script> tags are where they should be in order to ensure the form is populated before execution, and I used some elementID code to loop through my elements and present names/id's and values to be sure they weren't blank.  But some for some reason, running the above code gives me that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as was said before using `console.log` will fix your first problem. I see a second problem and that is how you are handling the `strOutput` var. The way you have it written will cause you to handle an `undefined` variable since the request is asynchronous. You should only use it in the callback function for `onreadystatechange` like below to ensure you use it when the request is finished.

```js
function validateSSO() {

  console.log("Starting function.....!")
  var fname = document.getElementById("usrSSO");
  console.log(fname.value)
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      if (this.status == 200){
        var strOutput = xmlhttp.responseText
        console.log("Function value: " + strOutput);
        if (strOutput == "A") {
          alert("Condition met - SSO is valid")
        } 
        else {
          alert("Nope - invalid");
        }
      }
      else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request. status code: ' + this.status);
      }
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "url", true)
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<header>Whittle ERP Ecosystem</header>
<p style="font-family:GE Inspira Sans;font-size:18px">This form is for raising Incidents against the pillar applications in the Whittle ERP Ecosystem
</p>
<p style="font-family:GE Inspira Sans;font-size:18px;color:red;font-
weight:bold">ALL FIELDS ARE MANDATORY</p>
<form id="frm1" action="" method="post" name="incForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>User Detail</legend>
    <label for="user-SSO">*SSO</label>
    <input type="text" name="usrSSO" id="usrSSO" value="108013590" required>
    <input type="Button" onclick="validateSSO()" value="Post">
    <label for="user-tel">&nbsp*Contact Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="user-tel" id="user-tel" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>System</legend>
    <label for="*Choose System">Choose System:</label>
    <select name="system" id="system" required>
            <option value="R12">R12</option>
            <option value="Proficy">Proficy</option>
            <option value="TipQA">TipQA</option>
        </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>*Brief Description</legend>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="60" name="bDesc" required></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>*Detailed Description</legend>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="dDesc" required></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Action</legend>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Yep, understood.  Thanks for expanding on this Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what's happening is that your `document.write` function is replacing the entire document with that one line of text, if you change `document.write` to `console.log` your problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks Shaheed, it would appear I'm a lazy dabbler and ought to have looked in to using the console for this.